# Does MATLAB optimize diag(A*B)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

Say I have two very big matrices `A` (M-by-N) and `B` (N-by-M). I need the diagonal of `A*B`. Computing the full `A*B` requires M*M*N multiplications, while computing the diagonal of it only requires M*N multiplications since there's no need to compute the elements that will end up outside the diagonal.

Does MATLAB realize this and on-the-fly-optimize `diag(A*B)` automagically, or am I better off using a for loop in this case?

Comment: Typicaly how big are those numbers - N and M?

Comment: The application where I encountered this question is where A is weight vectors in an artificial neural network and B is the difference between the input vector and another weight matrix. In this particular case M would be somewhere between 100 and 1000, and N = 4. So my original application may not actually qualify as "very big matrices". :P

Comment: If all the benchmarking done in the answers suggests that `diag(A*B)` isn't optimized on the fly, contact MathWorks with a feature request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can also implement `diag(A*B)` as `sum(A.*B',2)`. Let's benchmark this along with all other implementations/solutions as suggested for this question.

The different methods implemented as functions are listed below for benchmarking purposes:

1. Sum-multiplication method-1

   ```
   function out = sum_mult_method1(A,B)

   out = sum(A.*B',2);
   ```
2. Sum-multiplication method-2

   ```
   function out = sum_mult_method2(A,B)

   out = sum(A.'.*B).';
   ```
3. For-loop method

   ```
   function out = for_loop_method(A,B)

   M = size(A,1);
   out = zeros(M,1);
   for i=1:M
       out(i) = A(i,:) * B(:,i);
   end
   ```
4. Full/Direct-multiplication method

   ```
   function out = direct_mult_method(A,B)

   out = diag(A*B);
   ```
5. Bsxfun-method

   ```
   function out = bsxfun_method(A,B)

   out = sum(bsxfun(@times,A,B.'),2);
   ```

**Benchmarking Code**

```
num_runs = 1000;
M_arr = [100 200 500 1000];
N = 4;

%// Warm up tic/toc.
tic();
elapsed = toc();
tic();
elapsed = toc();

for k2 = 1:numel(M_arr)
    M = M_arr(k2);

    fprintf('\n')
    disp(strcat('*** Benchmarking sizes are M =',num2str(M),' and N = ',num2str(N)));

    A = randi(9,M,N);
    B = randi(9,N,M);

    disp('1. Sum-multiplication method-1');
    tic
    for k = 1:num_runs
        out1 = sum_mult_method1(A,B);
    end
    toc
    clear out1

    disp('2. Sum-multiplication method-2');
    tic
    for k = 1:num_runs
        out2 = sum_mult_method2(A,B);
    end
    toc
    clear out2

    disp('3. For-loop method');
    tic
    for k = 1:num_runs
        out3 = for_loop_method(A,B);
    end
    toc
    clear out3

    disp('4. Direct-multiplication method');
    tic
    for k = 1:num_runs
        out4 = direct_mult_method(A,B);
    end
    toc
    clear out4

    disp('5. Bsxfun method');
    tic
    for k = 1:num_runs
        out5 = bsxfun_method(A,B);
    end
    toc
    clear out5

end
```

**Results**

```
*** Benchmarking sizes are M =100 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 0.015242 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 0.015180 seconds.
3. For-loop method
Elapsed time is 0.192021 seconds.
4. Direct-multiplication method
Elapsed time is 0.065543 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 0.054149 seconds.

*** Benchmarking sizes are M =200 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 0.009138 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 0.009428 seconds.
3. For-loop method
Elapsed time is 0.435735 seconds.
4. Direct-multiplication method
Elapsed time is 0.148908 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 0.030946 seconds.

*** Benchmarking sizes are M =500 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 0.033287 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 0.026405 seconds.
3. For-loop method
Elapsed time is 0.965260 seconds.
4. Direct-multiplication method
Elapsed time is 2.832855 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 0.034923 seconds.

*** Benchmarking sizes are M =1000 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 0.026068 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 0.032850 seconds.
3. For-loop method
Elapsed time is 1.775382 seconds.
4. Direct-multiplication method
Elapsed time is 13.764870 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 0.044931 seconds.
```

**Intermediate Conclusions**

Looks like `sum-multiplication` methods are the best approaches, though `bsxfun` approach seems be to catching up with them as `M` increases from 100 to 1000.

Next, higher benchmarking sizes were tested with just the `sum-multiplication` and `bsxfun` methods. The sizes were -

```
M_arr = [1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000];
```

The results are -

```
*** Benchmarking sizes are M =1000 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 0.030390 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 0.032334 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 0.047377 seconds.

*** Benchmarking sizes are M =2000 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 0.040111 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 0.045132 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 0.060762 seconds.

*** Benchmarking sizes are M =5000 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 0.099986 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 0.103213 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 0.117650 seconds.

*** Benchmarking sizes are M =10000 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 0.375604 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 0.273726 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 0.226791 seconds.

*** Benchmarking sizes are M =20000 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 1.906839 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 1.849166 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 1.344905 seconds.

*** Benchmarking sizes are M =50000 and N =4
1. Sum-multiplication method-1
Elapsed time is 5.159177 seconds.
2. Sum-multiplication method-2
Elapsed time is 5.081211 seconds.
5. Bsxfun method
Elapsed time is 3.866018 seconds.
```

**Alternate benchmarking Code (with `timeit)**

```
num_runs = 1000;
M_arr = [1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000 100000 200000 500000 1000000];
N = 4;

timeall = zeros(5,numel(M_arr));
for k2 = 1:numel(M_arr)
    M = M_arr(k2);

    A = rand(M,N);
    B = rand(N,M);

    f = @() sum_mult_method1(A,B);
    timeall(1,k2) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() sum_mult_method2(A,B);
    timeall(2,k2) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() bsxfun_method(A,B);
    timeall(5,k2) = timeit(f);
    clear f

end

figure,
hold on
plot(M_arr,timeall(1,:),'-ro')
plot(M_arr,timeall(2,:),'-ko')
plot(M_arr,timeall(5,:),'-.b')
legend('sum-method1','sum-method2','bsxfun-method')
xlabel('M ->')
ylabel('Time(sec) ->')
```

**Plot**

[image]

**Final Conclusions**

It seems `sum-multiplication` method is great till certain stage, which is around `M=5000` mark and after that `bsxfun` seems to have a slight upper-hand.

**Future Work**

One can look into varying `N` and study the performances for the implementations mentioned here.

Comment: Those times look pretty small to be reliable and you're not doing any warm up. If you're not familiar with doing reliable benchmarking, but you have a recent Matlab, I suggest using `timeit`. Also, how about testing `bsxfun`?

Comment: @horchler Well those numbers are what OP is using as suggested in comments. Looking into timeit now.

Comment: Those may be the sizes of the matrices, but that doesn't mean that you can't do more runs and perhaps more importantly, warm up the functions before timing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is one of the rare cases where a for loop is better.

I ran the following script through the profiler:

```
M = 5000;
N = 5000;

A = rand(M, N); B = rand(N, M);
product = A*B;
diag1 = diag(product);

A = rand(M, N); B = rand(N, M);
diag2 = diag(A*B);

A = rand(M, N); B = rand(N, M);
diag3 = zeros(M,1);
for i=1:M
    diag3(i) = A(i,:) * B(:,i);
end
```

I reset A and B between each test just in case MATLAB would try to speed anything up by caching.

Result (edited for brevity):

```
  time   calls  line
  6.29       1    5 product = A*B; 
< 0.01       1    6 diag1 = diag(product); 

  5.46       1    9 diag2 = diag(A*B); 

             1   12 diag3 = zeros(M,1); 
             1   13 for i=1:M 
  0.52    5000   14     diag3(i) = A(i,:) * B(:,i); 
< 0.01    5000   15 end
```

As we can see, the for loop variant is an order of magnitude faster than the other two in this case. While the `diag(A*B)` variant is actually faster than the `diag(product)` variant, it's marginal at best.

I tried some different values of M and N, and in my tests the for loop variant is slower only if M=1.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you *can* do this faster than a `for` loop using the wonders of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
diag4 = sum(bsxfun(@times,A,B.'),2)
```

This about twice as fast as the explicit `for` loop on my machine for large matrices (2,000-by-2,000  and bigger) and is faster for matrices larger than about 500-by-500.

Note that all of these methods will produce numerically different results because of the different orders of summation and multiplication.

Comment: +1 for this approach, and for the very appropriate note on numerical differences. If you have the benchmarking code maybe you could compare my solution too and tell the results?

Comment: @LuisMendo: The `bsxfun` method is about 20% faster than your solution for the 5,000-by-5,000 case. I think it might be the parallelization implicit in the method.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. That's one more reason to like `bsxfun`.  However, `.*` and `sum` [are claimed](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958-which-matlab-functions-benefit-from-multithreaded-computation) to benefit from parallelization too...

Answer (score 3):

You can compute only the diagonal elements without a loop: just use

```
sum(A.'.*B).'
```

or

```
sum(A.*B.',2)
```

Comment: Or `sum(A.*B',2)`. I have some benchmarking results on this, coming up! Hope thats okay!

Comment: @Divakar Great! I had just asked @horchler for that. BTW, I tend to avoid the `,2` in `sum` on the basis that it's slower, but now I'm not sure that feeling is correct

Comment: Yeah, I realized shortly after submitting my answer, and was just about to edit that in. :)

Comment: @LuisMendo Added separate benchmarking results for your implementation too! `timeit` is what I am looking into now, to verify if the benchmarking results presented here are reliable.