# How to create a matrix from a row vector and a column vector without using a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, vector, vectorization

I have two vectors, say `A` of size nx1, and `B` of size 1xm. I want to create a result matrix `C` (nxm) from a non-linear formula so that

```
C(i,j) = A(i)/(A(i)+B(j)).
```

I know I can do this with a loop such as:

```
for i=1:n,
    C(i,1:m)=A(i)./(A(i)+B(1:m));
end
```

but is it possible in some way to do this without using a loop?

EDIT: Thanks for your answers! As a small addition, before I saw them a friend suggested the following solution:

```
C = A*ones(1,m)./(ones(n,1)*B+A*ones(1,m))
```

Comment: Can you provide a timing to compare performance of different methods?

Comment: @rahnema You can find the comparison below in Suever's answer. I'm a little busy to add my own answer, but I'm sure it's easy using Sueve's code.

Comment: It is better than `repmat` but worse than `bsxfun`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on MATLAB R2016a or earlier you'll want to use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to accomplish this

```
result = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, bsxfun(@plus, A, B));
```

If you are on R2016b or newer, then there is implicit expansion which allows you to remove `bsxfun` and just apply the element-operators directly

```
result = A ./ (A + B);
```

**Benchmark**

Here is a real benchmark using `timeit` to compare the execution speed of using `bsxfun`, `repmat`, implicit broadcasting and a `for` loop. As you can see from the results, the `bsxfun` and implicit broadcasting methods yield the fastest execution time.

```
function comparision()

    sz = round(linspace(10, 5000, 30));

    times1 = nan(size(sz));
    times2 = nan(size(sz));
    times3 = nan(size(sz));
    times4 = nan(size(sz));

    for k = 1:numel(sz)
        A = rand(sz(k), 1);
        B = rand(1, sz(k));
        times1(k) = timeit(@()option1(A,B));
        A = rand(sz(k), 1);
        B = rand(1, sz(k));
        times2(k) = timeit(@()option2(A,B));
        A = rand(sz(k), 1);
        B = rand(1, sz(k));
        times3(k) = timeit(@()option3(A,B));
        A = rand(sz(k), 1);
        B = rand(1, sz(k));
        times4(k) = timeit(@()option4(A,B));
    end

    figure
    p(1) = plot(sz, times1 * 1000, 'DisplayName', 'bsxfun');
    hold on
    p(2) = plot(sz, times2 * 1000, 'DisplayName', 'repmat');
    p(3) = plot(sz, times3 * 1000, 'DisplayName', 'implicit');
    p(4) = plot(sz, times4 * 1000, 'DisplayName', 'for loop');
    ylabel('Execution time (ms)')
    xlabel('Elements in A')
    legend(p)
end

function C = option1(A,B)
    C = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, bsxfun(@plus, A, B));
end

function C = option2(A,B)
    m = numel(B);
    n = numel(A);
    C = repmat(A,1,m) ./ (repmat(A,1,m) + repmat(B,n,1));
end

function C = option3(A, B)
    C = A ./ (A + B);
end

function C = option4(A, B)
    m = numel(B);
    n = numel(A);
    C = zeros(n, m);
    for i=1:n,
        C(i,1:m)=A(i)./(A(i)+B(1:m));
    end
end
```

[image]

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559922/how-much-faster-is-implicit-expansion-compared-with-bsxfun) for more information comparing implicit expansion and `bsxfun`.

Comment: I'm not sure `B` should be transposed? I get a "Non-singleton dimensions not equal" error unless I run it as `bsxfun(@rdivide, A, bsxfun(@plus, A, B));`

Comment: @Wolfie You're right, I didn't realize that `B` was a row vector.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit expansion is the way to go if you have 2016b or newer, as mentioned by Suever. Another approach without that is to do element-wise operations after making A and B the same size as C, using `repmat`...

```
A1 = repmat(A,1,m);
B1 = repmat(B,n,1);
C = A1 ./ (A1 + B1);
```

Or in 1 line...

```
C = repmat(A,1,m) ./ (repmat(A,1,m) + repmat(B,n,1));
```

As a benchmark, I ran your loop method, the above `repmat` method, and Suever's `bsxfun` method for `m = 1000, n = 100`, averaging over 1,000 runs each:

```
Using for loop 0.00290520 sec
Using repmat   0.00014693 sec
Using bsxfun   0.00016402 sec
```

So for large matrices, `repmat` and `bsxfun` are comparable with `repmat` edging it. For small matrices though, just looping can be quicker than both, especially with a small `n` as that's your loop variable!

It's worth testing the given methods for your specific use case, as the timing results seem fairly variable depending on the inputs.

Comment: When benchmarking it's best to use `timeit` as that guarantees a relatively stable estimate of execution time. See my updated post for a comparison of all methods.

Comment: @Suever nice one, I knew `timeit` existed but have never really used it, nice to see your example. I assume that the `repmat` method also uses more memory than `bsxfun`, so I was expecting it to be slower!